# running docker project on localhost but nothing is coming up

Tags: python, docker

I have a docker image that was build. I want to run it on localhost and see the project on my local machine. When i run the image, i see it in the docker ps. when i go to localhost, I get nothing. I am not sure if it is the port  that i am trying to run or permissions, or something like that...

here is the command i am running:

```
λ docker run -p 5050:80 opentab
```

here is after the image was built:

```
Successfully built 7e995fbdf2ea
Successfully tagged opentab:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

here is the docker file:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./

EXPOSE 80

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

I had to remove the following from the requirements file because they were causing errors:

python
sqlite
tk
zx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) `manage.py runserver` will bind to localhost only by default. This localhost is INSIDE the container, not on your computer. As such, you want to bind the application to all interfaces like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0
```

2) `manage.py runserver` will bind to port 8000 by default. So, two options. One, you can make manage.py runserver bind to port 80, like so:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.0:80
```

Or, you would change your dockerfile, replacing `EXPOSE 80` with `EXPOSE 8000`, and change your docker command to `docker run -p 5050:8000 opentab`

Comment: if i wanted to use the first option that you put `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`, would i have to put parens between each item like the following...
`CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:80"]` or without the parens

Comment: I tried both ways to get it to run, but it is still not running for some reason.. this is what my docker file looks like `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt COPY . . CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"] `. and i am running the following command to run the project after i build the project.. `docker run -p 8000:8000 opentab`. I also tried running it without the port and i get an error that it couldnt connect... @MrName

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, that all looks correct. Did you expose port 8000 in your dockerfile?